# How can I redirect all url requests to index.php/path/variables except those starting with img/?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache

I have some simple RewriteRules that redirect all path variables to /index.php.  But now I'm looking to make an exception for all /img/(.*) urls.

Here's a snippet.  Please advise.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

I tried adding `RewriteRule ^img/(.*) img/index.php/$1 [L]` just above the last catchall line but it's not working.

The result I'm after is something like this:

```
url      --> script / path variables
====================================
/abc/def --> /index.php/abc/def
/img/abc --> /img/index.php/abc
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it not just above the last catchall line, but leave the conditions required by the catchall and likewise duplicate them for your own `/img/` routing:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^img/(.*) img/index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```